# C# - Adobe OLE JSObject - Value does not fall within the expected range

Tags: c#, acrobat, late-binding, comobject

I'm switching over code from VB to C#, and with C# I'm getting a `System.ArgumentException` with the message `Value does not fall within the expected range.`

I know I must be missing something stupid simple, but as soon as I try to use any property or method of the `jso`, I get the exception.

```
AcroApp acroApp = new AcroApp();
AcroAVDoc acroAV = new AcroAVDoc();
if (acroAV.Open(LoadFilePath, string.Empty))
{
    AcroPDDoc acroPD = acroAV.GetPDDoc();
    dynamic jso = acroPD.GetJSObject();
    if (jso.NumFields > 0)
    {
        // Code never reaches here.
    }
}
```

I was originally late binding the other Adobe objects, and thought that might have been the issue. But, whether I use the type library or late bind, the code works fine up until the `jso` object.

With VB the code would look like this and works without any issues:

```
Dim acroApp As New AcroApp()
Dim acroAV As New AcroAVDoc()
If AcroAV.Open(LoadFilePath, String.Empty())
    Dim acroPD As AcroPDDoc = acroAV.GetPDDoc()
    Dim jso As Object = acroPD.GetJSObject()
    If jso.NumFields > 0 Then
        ' Code that does stuff
    End If
End If
```

Comment: With C#, when I change the type of `jso` to `object` (rather than `dynamic`) and retrieve its properties with `jso.GetType().GetProperties()` then it gives an empty property collection, meaning no `NumFields` at hand. But with VB.NET things get really interesting. When I inspect the `jso.NumFields` expression in the debugger, it displays its value of 0 correctly. As you said, the Acrobat OLE type library is happy with VB.NET but it seems it is not a good fit with C#. I couldn't see public C# examples in the Adobe docs.

Comment: One workaround for you might be using the [iText7](https://www.nuget.org/packages/itext7) library for your PDF stuff.

Comment: A constraint of my work environment is being stuck with Adobe for this. I'd much rather be using a 3rd-party library for this.

Comment: I ended up going a different route with it by getting the type and invoking the calls. It seems clunkier than it needs to be, but it does work.